# Input double when click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have modal and drop down input..
when Drop Down click text in button drop-down has append text into text field..
if input first time success, no problem, but..
if modal close and open modal again, when drop down click, value in input field double..

**JS:**

```
$("#test").on("click", 'td', function() {
  var usr = $(this).text();
  $("#s").val(function() {

    return this.value + usr;

  });
});
```

Comment: reset value when open model.

Comment: i use $('#form')[0].reset(); not work..

Comment: Try to provide a live example

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").on("click", 'td', function() {
  var usr = $(this).text();
 if($("#s").val()){
    $("#s").reset();
  }
  $("#s").val(function() {

    return this.value + usr;

  });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.